# New to EE 3.3.0 Ver - Cannot Assign Status Group To Channel

Tags: status, groups

I am new to Expression Engine 3.3.0. I have a "News" Channel group and "News" field status group that I want to assign so I can separate my news articles from the ones that show at the top of my site from the three that show underneath. See here for details..
http://www.mannachurch.org/ExpressionEngine/

The new UX is great....but, um....I can't assign this for some reason. I only have the option to assign my Status Groups "Homepage Featured" and "Homepage Secondary." My "Homepage Featured" and " Homepage Secondary" should be in my "News" Channel fields group, What am I doing wrong? This is test site, with no sensitive material there, so if you need access lemme know.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I got it. This interface is confusing. I had to click on the "eye" in order to get into the Status field group.